# decrease font size on exisiting text in pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have a huge pdf containing >1000 pages, need to edit existing text, offcourse it is added by me using pdfbox [addtext to each page example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddMessageToEachPage.java?view=markup) ... the text font size was very big text runs out of page..
now i want to decrease the size of font so that it will be within page limits... or i can clear the existing text and replace a the same text with new font...

Comment: Can't you just restart with the original files?

Comment: :( made changes on the actual file didn't backup

Comment: If you used the code you linked to, then you will find the "added message" in the content stream array, as the second last item. Open the PDF file with PDFDebugger and you will see what I mean. You could then delete this item progranmatically (something like `PDPage.getCosObject().getItem(COSName.Contents)`) and save the file. Please link to such a file (maybe create one that is representative - have a look at it with PDFDebugger too).

Comment: tried PDFDebugger not sure what to see... by the way i used textMatrix to add text message has shown in example of pdfbox...

Comment: If you don't see the page displayed, then in the menu, click "View", "Show Pages". Then click on the "+" on the left. Then click on the "+" on the left of "Contents". You can now see the content stream array.

Comment: my bad i can able to see the contents menu on left hand side.. but that is not in understandable format... changed top unfiltered to Filtered(flatedecode) still not readable

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://s32.postimg.org/s0o2zz2sl/pdfdebugger_screenshot.png

Comment: yeah that textview tab contents are not readable how can know what that means?

Comment: Grab the PDF specification and look for "operator summary". But you don't have to read it. If you used the code you mentioned, the content stream to be deleted is the second last.

Comment: ha ha :)...  wasting time on understading PDFDebugger, removing second last item done trick, COSArray  array = ((COSArray) page.getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.CONTENTS));
    array.remove(array.size() - 1); thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**credits to [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) for answer**

If you used the code you linked to, then you will find the "added message" in the content stream array, as the second last item. `PDPage.getCosObject().getItem(COSName.Contents)` and save the file.

```
public void removeStamp(File src) throws IOException {
         PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(src);
         PDPageTree pages = doc.getPages();

         for (PDPage page : pages) {
             COSArray  array = ((COSArray) page.getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.CONTENTS));
             array.remove(array.size() - 1);
         }
         doc.save(src);
    }
```